# I wish to stop this right to left horizontal auto scroll

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

http://www.myprovence.fr/snapshots2012/fr/marseille-provence/0-carte.html

This above mentioned website got an auto scroll from right to left. Since its my project inspiration, I am asked to stop this auto scroll only. Other features will remain as it is. But I am failed to understand, how could i stop auto scroll. Appreciate helps.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: firstly produce some code that will auto scroll the contents. Then you ask about stopping it.

Comment: @gourav I have a code(plugin) but since it is too large, I cant paste it on message board.

Comment: Then how can we help you???

Comment: Is there any option to attach files?